# AngularJS "Constant" Factory

Tags: configuration, angularjs, constants, factory

I'm working on setting up configuration files in AngularJS. Is it possible to create a factory in AngularJS whose key cannot be overwritten? For example, I can set up a constant like this, which cannot be overwritten

> module.constant('animals', {"cat": "meow", "dog": "woof"});

But I'd like to do something like this that allows for overwritten *values* but not the factory itself

```
module.value('catSound','meow')
      .value('dogSound','woof')
      .factory('animals', ['catSound','dogSound', function(catSound, dogSound) {
            return {
                 "cat": catSound,
                 "dog": dogSound
            }
      });
```

The above factory can be overwritten allowing for another piece of code to have `module.factory('animals',function(){ return 7 })` and break everything. However, as a factory, the individual values *can* (and should) be overwritable, so I should be able to assign `module.value('catSound','hiss')` and have things still work as expected.

I've tried injecting into constants, but as far as I've been able to understand that isn't possible. How can I prevent my factory declaration from being overwritten? I realize that *constant* probably isn't the correct term when describing what I want, but I do want the factory's function *definition* to be constant.

Comment: Can you provide a little insight into your use case? Overwriting factories provides great benefits, for example in mocking for tests.

Comment: Essentially I'm just trying to set up a default configuration file that can be copied and have its parameters modified to fit the needs of individual servers (i.e., we'll want an API URL pointing to a development API by default, but on the production server we'll want it pointing to the production API). The idea was to maintain _all_ of the configuration values in one file to make updating default values simple, while preventing devs from accidentally altering the factory's output in their local configuration. `value()` would allow for individual changes. I'm sure there's a better method

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to your problem? I am dealing with the same issue at the moment.

Comment: Nothing I'm particularly pleased about. I've put the `factory()` method under a global namespace and am checking for its existence. If the namespace exists, I don't call the factory method again.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is mutable in javascript, so setting up something like this is tricky and never completely fail-safe. I've looked around in the angular code and found no evidence of any attempt at a protection mechanism like you seem to be asking for.

My advise would be to just live with the risk. It's not worth trying to protect yourself other than with tests and nice long names. I assume you've been bitten once, but I think the chances are quite low, unless you define factories with very short names.

Comment: Granted, but things like `Object.seal()` and setters can provide a degree of protection. `module.constant()` prevents items from being overwritten using the same method more than once, so I was hoping something similar was already in place for `module.factory()` definitions.

Comment: @IanHunter yes, agreed. I don't think there is anything in place right now though, so you either have to do it yourself or live without...